# Mac to IOS tethering via USB stopped working

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, tethering

i've been using the usb tether for years but it stopped working this week and i can't find any issues/errors. i can still tether via wifi hotspot but when i plug it into usb, it does not do anything.

its hard to troubleshoot because in the past i never had to do anything to make it work.

running high sierra 10.13.3 and iphone 6 with latest updates.
how can i troubleshoot USB tethering?